# I have problems for export from Blender to Ogre3D

Tags: blender, ogre, blender-game-engine

I don't speak good english, but I will try..
I need to make a game for my University.
Exists lot of models in **blendswap** but, I have problem for export.

Many of these models have extra objects, such as a floor, I need to remove those extra objects and export the weapon and hand.

My idea is:

Import a weapon model with hand with 2 actions, reload and shoot.
**How can I do it?**

I love this models:

http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/85257 or 67870 or 70607 (change number in link, because I don't can put more 1 link, because I'm level noob)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the blender2ogre exporter: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=blender2ogre

If the plugin doesn't export .mesh files, and only exports .xml files, use the XML converter tool on the XML files to produce the .mesh files: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/OgreXmlConverter

As far as only exporting the weapon and not the floor, this is a matter of Blender editing. You will need to select only the geometry you wish to export, and check the "Export selected only" option. You may have to go into mesh editing mode, and cut out the triangles that you don't want, depending on the model.

Comment: I used blender2ogre.. In Ubuntu the export is perfect, but in windows only export .XML, so I use Ubuntu. I can not edit it, do you think you can help me? I do can paying, I need to do my college project soon.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, you should just run "OgreXMLConverter.exe Model.mesh.xml" on the exported .XML file, then you will get the Ogre mesh.